# Object.any_instance in rspec(v. 1.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

what's the alias for **[any_instance](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class)** in rspec v1.2?

```
Object.any_instance.stub(:foo).and_return("return_value")
```

P.S.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "hack" was to to redefine a class' method in scope of the test: 
e.g. if you want to make a stub like:

```
SomeClass.any_instance.stub(:foo).and_return(return_value)
```

--

```
describe SomeClass
  class SomeClass
    def foo
      return "return value"
    end
  end
  # your test goes here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one. `any_instance` was first supported in rspec-2.6: http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/file/Changelog.md.

Comment: What about some hacks or anything the similar result may be achieved with?